# How can i load multiple custom views in collection view swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, custom-view

I have two collection view cells A and B , i need to load these cells simultaneously. But i didn't found any solutions

```
         firstCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "A", bundle:  Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "A")
     firstCollectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "B", bundle:  Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "B")
```

These are the two views and how can load 2 views at time.

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "A", for:indexPath) as? A
```

Comment: In the same section or same cell or any other condition?

Comment: what do you mean simultaneously ? ... do you need two different cells or ?

Comment: You can just dequence both A and B at same time and choose which one you want to return

Comment: i meant load A and then B.

Comment: check the indexPath number and return the correct cell, thats all

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to divide the different cells type? with number? Like, if raw = 0,2,4,6 etc you will have firstCell and if raw = 1,3,5 etc you will have secendCell?

So maybe with something like this :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = UICollectionViewCell()

        cell = collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "B", bundle:  Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "B")

        if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
            cell = collectionView..register(UINib(nibName: "A", bundle:  Bundle.main), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "A")
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Register `CustomCollectionViewCell` in the `viewDidLoad:`

```
    var nib1 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell1", bundle: nil)
    self.firstCollectionView().registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
    var nib2 = UINib(nibName: "CustomCollectionViewCell2", bundle: nil)
    self.firstCollectionView().registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
```

Now return your cell here `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method,

```
//As per your condition check cell index or section or any other your condition.


 if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {  

      // Create an instance of CustomCollectionViewCell1
     var cell: CustomCollectionViewCell1? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
        if self.cell == nil {
            self.cell = CustomCollectionViewCell1(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell1")
        }
     return cell!

    }else{
      // Create an instance of CustomCollectionViewCell2
     var cell: CustomCollectionViewCell2? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
        if self.cell == nil {
            self.cell = CustomCollectionViewCell2(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "CustomCell2")
        }
     return cell!
    }
```